# How to work with React Hooks in jest / enzyme tests?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that has useState and an updateTotalSum function that triggers setTotalSum. How can I test and get the value from useState (totalSum), and also call the updateTotalSum function

```
//My component

const SomeComponent = props => {
  const [totalSum, setTotalSum] = useState(null);

  const updateTotalSum = sum => {
  //...do something
  setTotalSum(sum);
  }

  return <AnotherComponent updateTotalSum={updateTotalSum} totalSum={totalSum} />
}

//My tests

// Sample test for component class. Everything works correctly.
it('should correctly called updateTotalSum method', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />;
  wrapper.instance().updateTotalSum(1000);
  expect(wrapper.state('totalSum')).toBe(1000);
});

// Test for the functional component. Expected, not working
it('should correctly called updateTotalSum method', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />;
  wrapper.updateTotalSum(1000);
  expect(wrapper.totalSum).toBe(1000);
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't test the value in the state or interact with the instance methods. Indeed you *can't* do the latter, because they're just local variables. Instead test the *behaviour* - e.g. stub out `AnotherComponent` and make sure the interactions with that are correct.

Comment: Enzyme doesn't support hooks yet. According to [this issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2011) partial support was merged but not yet released.